# Mysql generated always as column multiply variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, stored-functions

```
SELECT @a:= deger1 FROM iscilik1 WHERE Id=16;
ALTER TABLE iscilik1kisiler MODIFY COLUMN deger4 DECIMAL GENERATED ALWAYS AS (@a*deger3) STORED;
```

Hi everyone.I have a problem with this code and giving error like this;[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgMpn.jpg)

I could not find where is the problem.Thanks for everything have a good jobs.

Comment: You can't use a variable in a generated column.  You could construct a string and execute this as dynamic SQL.

Comment: Sorry I'm very amateur about sql.Can you give a same sample for me this sql query?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html

Comment: Please never present textual details (like errors) as screenshots.  Vision impaired users cannot read your screenshot -- neither can search engine crawlers.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT CONCAT( 'ALTER TABLE iscilik1kisiler ',
               'MODIFY COLUMN deger4 DECIMAL ',
               'GENERATED ALWAYS AS (',
               deger1,
               '*deger3) STORED' )
INTO @sql
FROM iscilik1 
WHERE Id=16;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DROP PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.